# C Program will compile and run in Linux but not Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, ubuntu

I'm working on an assignment for a programming class and am having an issue with a program. The goal is to take in a set of user defined values, store them in an array, then find the closest pair of numbers (the numbers with the smallest difference). The numbers don't have to have consecutive indices. Also, the array size of 50 is defined in the assignment by the professor.

The problem I'm running into is that the program will compile in both Linux (Ubuntu 14.xx) and Windows 10, however, when I run the result in Linux, it works fine but in Windows it outputs nothing.

This is the first time I've had this issue and as far as I know I didn't use any system specific commands. Any help provided would be appreciated.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, a, b, temp, mindiff, count;
    int numarray[50];

    count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &numarray[i]);
        count++;
        if (numarray[i] == -1)
        {
            numarray[i] = 0;
            count--;
            break;
        }
    }
    mindiff = 100;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            a = numarray[i];
            b = numarray[j];
            if (a != b)
                if (a > b)
                    temp = a - b;
                else    
                    temp = b - a;

            if (temp < mindiff)
                mindiff = temp;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            a = numarray[i];
            b = numarray[j];
            if (a != b) 
            {
                if (a > b && (a - b) == mindiff)
                {
                    printf("Closest pair: %d and %d, Difference: %d\n", a, b, mindiff);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In Windows, how exactly are you compiling and running this program?  What kind of command-line terminal are you using to run it?  What input are you supplying, and how?

Comment: try `if (a != b){
 if (a > b)
  temp = a - b;
 else 
  temp = b - a;

    if (temp < mindiff)
     mindiff = temp;
}`

Comment: You should check `scanf()` for errors and `main` should be at least `int main(void){}`

Comment: On Linux, compile with `gcc -Wall test.c -o test.exe`. It will alert you to three potential problems. You might even use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two major problems:

- Your code has undefined behavior because you use `temp` even if it has not been set (you should start a block after `if (a != b)`). *undefined behavior* means anything can happen, including apparent success on Linux and failure on Windows.
- You initialize `mindiff` to `100`. If all numbers are farther apart from each other, `mindiff` will not be changed and the second loop will not print anything.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int count, i, j, mina, minb, mindiff;
    int numarray[50];

    for (count = 0; count < 50; count++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &numarray[count]) != 1 || numarray[count] == -1)
            break;
    }
    mindiff = mina = minb = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            int a = numarray[i];
            int b = numarray[j];
            if (a > b) {
                int diff = a - b;
                if (mindiff == 0 || mindiff > diff) {
                    mindiff = diff;
                    mina = a;
                    minb = b;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (mindiff == 0) {
        if (count == 0) {
            printf("No numbers input\n");
        } else {
            printf("The numbers are all identical\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Closest pair: %d and %d, Difference: %d\n",
               mina, minb, mindiff);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the temp variable was being set as 0, which meant temp was always < mindiff, setting mindiff to 0, which means that since (a != b) && (a - b) == mindiff is a contradiction. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: @Hunter: technically, `temp` was uninitialized, it *happens* to have been `0` on your machine, but it can have any value, including a different one on each run and possibly a value that can crash the program on some architectures... Enclosing `if (temp < mindiff)  mindiff = temp;` inside a block commanded by the `if (a != b)` test fixes this issue, but the special cases of `a[0]` being the largest and that of all identical values need attention too.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following problem:
Note: temp is considered a stack variable under the main function and since you do not initialize it, it becomes garbarge (for example a large negative number):

```
int i, j, a, b, temp, mindiff, count;
```

Then if temp is a large negative number, mindiff = the garbarge value of mindiff,

```
        if (temp < mindiff)
            mindiff = temp;
```

And the following if statement is always false.
    if (a > b && (a - b) == mindiff)

And nothing gets printed.

Comment: @EOF sorry, I fixed my mistake. I meant temp not mindiff

Comment: Hey, Dave, I did not downvote you. Not sure who did or why they would have done so. Your answer is correct.

Comment: @DaveS Thank you for the response. Your answer was correct and helped in identifying the problem. In Windows, my compiler (or runtime not sure which, not sure how that works yet) was setting temp = 0, which meant temp was always < mindiff. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @Hunter - Glad to have helped.  Unfortunately, its too bad I got a -1 for my post.

Comment: I did upvote your answer, however, as a new user, I didn't have enough reputation for it to show up on the public side. I do now and have done it again to reflect my appreciation. I am sorry someone has downvoted your answer. I suppose some just want to watch the world burn

Comment: @Hunter - Thanks, much appreciated.  Wishing you much success! David